# r: dplyr mutate error non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, dplyr

trying mutate in dplyr on the data.frame (list) but get an error: non-numeric argument to binary operator. tried converting delayed and 'on time' to numeric but still getting the error, is there an error in the code?

```
list$delayed <- as.numeric(as.character(list$delayed))
list$'on time' <- as.numeric(as.character(list$'on time'))

list <- mutate(list, total = delayed + 'on tine', pctdelay = delayed / total * 100)

   Carrier  City         delayed on time
1  Alaska   Los Angeles      62     497
2  Alaska       Phoenix      12     221
3  Alaska     San Diego      20     212
4  Alaska San Francisco     102     503
5  Alaska       Seattle     305    1841
6 AM WEST   Los Angeles     117     694
```

Comment: did you mean 'on time' rather than 'on tine'?

Comment: sorry, yes 'on time'

Comment: Try back ticks instead. And in general, try to avoid spaces in column names. In this case `'on tine'` is interpreted as a string

Comment: that worked, thank you so much. yes, i don't use spaces but this was an exercise to "tidy" the data given. thank you again for quick solution.